# Ploymorphism cannot invoke method

Tags: java

I am testing out a polymorphism in Java. I have the following code:

```
    public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String args[]){
        Object o = new Circle(10.0);
        doStuff(o);
    }
    
    public static void doStuff(Object myObject){
        System.out.println(myObject.getArea());
    }



}

class Circle{
    double radius;
    
    Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    
    double getArea(){
        return 3.14 * this.radius * this.radius;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

[image]

This does not make sense to me because polymorphism here should ensure that the `getArea()` method is binded during run-time.

Comment: The _implementation_ will be. The _interface_ is bound at compile-time.

Comment: You're not making it to runtime, though... the compiler is blocking you because you've declared that  the argument to `doStuff()` is `Object`, so unless you attempt to cast it back to `Circle` inside the method, you can only treat it as an `Object`

Comment: Override a method from `Object` instead, like `toString()`. First don't override `toString` and see what gets returned. Then do override it and run your program again. See the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is a [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language:

> Generally, a strongly typed language has stricter typing rules at compile time, which implies that errors and exceptions are more likely to happen during compilation. Most of these rules affect variable assignment, function return values, procedure arguments and function calling. Dynamically typed languages (where type checking happens at run time) can also be strongly typed. Note that in dynamically typed languages, values have types, not variables.

In your code `myObject` is defined as a `Object` type and there is no `getArea()` method on [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) so compiler throws an error.

Polymorphism happens during program execution, after the code is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the subclass and do a cast.

Common code pattern:

```
((Circle)myObject).getArea();
```

It's generally easier for a subclass to invoke superclass methods. As there may be many different subclasses, there is no way to know if a particular subclass's methods apply to a superclass instance, so the subclass has to be specified.

Comment: Why not just change `doStuff` to accept `Circle` instead of `Object`? Taking Object and then casting is bad advice. It bypasses the type system and the compiler checking types. It makes crashes at runtime more likely, when the compiler could flag problems at build time.

Comment: Yes, a situation arises where you are using this sort of pattern, it's good to take a second look and see if there is a better way to handle the situation.